# Why am I getting "Warning NaNs Produced" with ifelse?

Tags: r

I've got a pretty simple piecewise function that takes the vector argument `omega`:

```
btilde <- function(omega) {
        if(min(omega)<=0) stop("ALL ELEMENTS OF OMEGA MUST BE POSITIVE")
        ifelse( 0 < omega & omega <=  1, 0.233*omega^2,
        ifelse( 1 < omega & omega <=  3, 0.005*omega^4 - 0.06906*omega^3 + 0.3167*omega^2 - 0.02326*omega,
        ifelse( 3 < omega & omega <= 40, 0.705*sqrt(omega)*log(omega),
        ifelse(40 < omega,               sqrt(3*omega*log(omega) - log(8*pi) - 2/log(omega) - 170),
        NA))))
    }
```

I get a "Warning NaNs produced" if `omega=c(1,41)` but not if `omega=1` or `omega=41`.

```
> btilde(1)
[1] 0.233
> btilde(41)
[1] 16.8228
> btilde(c(1,41))
[1]  0.2330 16.8228
Warning message:
In sqrt(3 * omega * log(omega) - log(8 * pi) - 2/log(omega) - 170) :
  NaNs produced
```

If the ">40" condition is applied to "omega=1", then yes, I would get an `NaN`, but that's not how `ifelse()` works, right?  Can someone help me understand what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `ifelse` help page,

> ‘yes’ will be evaluated if and only if any element of ‘test’ is true, and analogously for ‘no’.

So the expression is evaluated, even if the individual element is `FALSE`, if any other element is `TRUE`. Consider the simple example

```
x = c(0, -1) 
ifelse(x == 0, sqrt(x), x)

[1]  0 -1
Warning message:
In sqrt(x) : NaNs produced
```

which produces a similar warning as your code.

Comment: I read the quoted text from the help page, but it didn't make sense to me on its own (i.e., in the help page); your example is helpful and analogous to my situation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to focus on one element in your algorithm and then `map` your function to a list. 
This is another version of your method with no warnings:

```
library(purrr)

btilde <- function(omega) {
  if (omega <= 0) stop("ALL ELEMENTS OF OMEGA MUST BE POSITIVE")
  if (omega <= 1) return (0.233*omega^2)
  if (omega <= 3) return (0.005*omega^4 - 0.06906*omega^3 + 0.3167*omega^2 - 0.02326*omega)
  if (omega <= 40) return(0.705*sqrt(omega)*log(omega))
  return(sqrt(3*omega*log(omega) - log(8*pi) - 2/log(omega) - 170))
}
```

The following is the output:

```
> map_dbl(c(1,41), ~ btilde(.x))
[1]  0.2330 16.8228
```